# Could not load file or assembly System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, nuget

I am working with Windows Forms Apps. **No error in the development or building of the setup on my machine. Everything working correctly.**

> **Throwing errors only when setup install and running the software on any other machine.**

The complete stack trace is given below.

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool' threw an exception. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058) ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Text.ValueStringBuilder.Dispose()
   at System.Text.ValueStringBuilder.ToString()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogValuesFormatter..ctor(String format)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerMessage.CreateLogValuesFormatter(String formatString, Int32 expectedNamedParameterCount)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerMessage.Define[T1,T2](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, String formatString, LogDefineOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerMessage.Define[T1,T2](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, String formatString)
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool..cctor() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 816
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetPool(String connectionString, MySqlConnectorLoggingConfiguration loggingConfiguration, Boolean createIfNotFound)
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.<OpenAsync>d__28.MoveNext() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 399
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.Open() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 381
   at DigitalSigner.DigitalSigner.Main.Main_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4515.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
DigitalSigner
    Assembly Version: 18.6.0.0
    Win32 Version: 18.6.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Pulkitsoft/Digital%20Signer/DigitalSigner.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 14.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4536.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4536.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4550.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4390.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4190.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------
itextsharp
    Assembly Version: 5.5.13.2
    Win32 Version: 5.5.13.2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Pulkitsoft/Digital%20Signer/itextsharp.DLL
----------------------------------------
MySqlConnector
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.3.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Pulkitsoft/Digital%20Signer/MySqlConnector.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4536.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions
    Assembly Version: 7.0.0.1
    Win32 Version: 7.0.723.27404
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Pulkitsoft/Digital%20Signer/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.DLL
----------------------------------------
AutoUpdater.NET
    Assembly Version: 1.6.4.0
    Win32 Version: 1.6.4.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Pulkitsoft/Digital%20Signer/AutoUpdater.NET.DLL
----------------------------------------
CustomMarshalers
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/CustomMarshalers/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/CustomMarshalers.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions
    Assembly Version: 4.2.0.1
    Win32 Version: 4.6.28619.01
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Pulkitsoft/Digital%20Signer/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Memory
    Assembly Version: 4.0.1.2
    Win32 Version: 4.6.31308.01
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Pulkitsoft/Digital%20Signer/System.Memory.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource
    Assembly Version: 7.0.0.2
    Win32 Version: 7.0.423.11508
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Pulkitsoft/Digital%20Signer/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe
    Assembly Version: 6.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 6.0.21.52210
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Pulkitsoft/Digital%20Signer/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.DLL
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

I tried to correct for three days, and try too many solution but nothing working.

Also, somewhere found answer and add binding redirect in app.config file, but not working.

```
<runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
```

Unable to understand what's goes wrong.

Comment: Your stack mentions a "System.BadImageFormatException" not what you have put in the question. Sound more like the bitness used by your application is different then the bitness of the native MySql code its tryping to load. Or its just a follow up problem of the problem you mention. But whatever its is it does not match.

Comment: Is the other machine running on same platform of the machine where the software was built ? If some assembly was compiled to run in an especific platform it will raise this exception while trying to run in a different one.

Comment: @Ralf Sorry for that I am not an expert. Have you a solution?

Comment: Try deploying the correct Sqlite stuff? I'm not familiar with sqlite. But guessing from the stack. It looks like you developed on a 64bit machine then deployed that to another machine (including sqllite stuff build for 64bit system) but the machine runs a 32bit OS.

Comment: @Ralf For your better understanding I am sharing you few details. Development machine: 64-bit, Visual Studio: 64-bit, Working project: Any CPU, Another machine where get the error: 64-bit. Till this time everything is fine for 2 years. Getting errors since started using the **MySqlConnector** Nuget package.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/1440) sounds pretty equal to your problem.